# Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

i want to app version update,but at the new version i add two new attribute at the core data,i want to  Migrate data from old version to new version. my step:

1. choice .xcdatamodeld file，then editor->Add Model Version
2. Design > Data Model > Set Current Version.
3. modify options

   ```
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],  NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,  
                                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],   NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];  
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error])
   ```

but my new version no found any data from the old version.
how to  modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my mistakes: PushNoticationModal.sqlite  not the same as the name  PushNoticationModel.xcdatamodel  ,you see PushNoticationModal not like PushNoticationModel.

when you only build one sqlite,the name PushNoticationModal.sqlite  ,not the same as PushNoticationModel.xcdatamodel,your app also can run.but when you build migration you should keep the same